# Spray.io with the latest spec2 version 3.6.4

Tags: rspec2, spray

I'm trying to use spray with the latest spec2 version 3.6.4.

I came across the below post but I am unsure if I really have to compile from source or if there is a simpler solution?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/2T6SBp4OJeI

Comment: No just put the file from https://gist.github.com/gmalouf/51a8722b50f6a9d30404 into your sources for the time being.

Comment: Thanks @jrudolph. I'm not exactly sure how to integrate it into my project. 
Would it be possible show me how to based on Spray's Getting started example: 

spray as a standalone service - this uses the spray-routing and spray-can modules
https://github.com/spray/spray-template/tree/on_spray-can_1.3